# How can I prioritize files to transfer using Google Drive (or similar software)?

Tags: google, google-drive

Is it possible to prioritize files to transfer using Google Drive, or with one of its competitors such as AeroFS or Dropbox? I'd like to be able to choose which files and folders to synchonize first, so that each of the files and folders are synchronized in a specific order.

Comment: Since you're talking about the sync feature, this is rather a [su] question rather than a Web Apps question. Unfortunately, this question is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Drive does not currently have this feature, but Sugarsync has a feature where you can select certain files to be high priority and uploaded before others.  At times, it is not as convenient as it should be, but it does work.

Comment: So how can you prioritize the files? I'd like to know how to access this feature.

Comment: It appears that the answer can be found here: http://sugarsync.hivelive.com/posts/75cf6a3e5c?commentId=11161#11161

Answer (score 5):

Put simply, no. It has been asked a few times on the Google Product Forums but no word yet on whether it will be introduced as a feature.

Comment: Do other file-synchronization services (such as Dropbox) support such a feature? It would be very useful if I could just right-click on a folder or file and select "Sync now" from the context menu, instead of waiting (perhaps hours) for the other files to finish syncing.

Comment: Dropbox, Sugarsync, Wuala and Box definitely do not. I don't know about others such as Amazon Cloud Drive and Microsoft Skydrive.

Comment: In fact, SugarSync does allow files to be prioritized - see here. http://sugarsync.hivelive.com/posts/75cf6a3e5c?commentId=11161#11161

Answer (score 0):

Closest to priority is to sync only the folders where you have the files that need to be prioritized.

Comment: How can you prioritize the files or the folders? I haven't heard of this feature before.